# Isn't ssh-copy-id exposing to a brute force attack?

Tags: ssh, brute-force, vulnerability

It is a common knowledge, that using keys to authenticate ssh users is more secure than using passwords. However, even with password login disabled, when running ssh-copy-id I am still asked for user's password. It makes me think - what stops the attacker from trying to brute force this password instead (and upload self-generated public key to gain permanent access)? Is it a security hole, or am I missing something important?

P.S. let's assume there is no fail2ban or similar software running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) is a script that simply logs onto a target machine and copies your public key there, so that further login attempts on that machine can be done with your SSH private key. This assumes that you *can* log on that machine right now, while your public key is not there. If you get asked for a password, then this means that password-based login is still enabled on that server (or at least that the client is trying to authenticate with a password, which may or may not work depending on server configuration).

Comment: Thanks! I've been misled with ssh-copy-id asking me for password - I've never checked if entering the correct one will allow me to upload another key. However, I'm afraid I can't agree with everything you've said - while it's true I can't upload a new key that way, the `If you get asked for a password, then this means that password-based login is still enabled on that server.` sentence doesn't seem to be true - I am asked for password even if I run `ssh a@x` but the password is being rejected (and yes, I am sure it's the correct one). I'll be happy to accept your answer if you fix that part :)

Comment: OK, I added a provision for that. Maybe entering the password would not have worked. Anyway, the important point is that ssh-copy-id is just an automation script that uses the normal SSH protocol and configuration; it is not an additional mechanism. The server is not even aware of the existence of ssh-copy-id.

Answer (score 1):

You are prompted to type a password each time you use it because it is the default behavior of that tool as you can read through its documentation:

> presumably using a login password, so password authentication should
>   be enabled, unless you've done some clever use of multiple identities

As for preventing bruteforce attacks, may be you can refer to the good practices listed via [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/594746/how-to-stop-prevent-ssh-bruteforce/594750#594750) in case you can not use fail2ban.

Comment: So it is the tool that's asking for the password and not the SSH server?

Comment: @NeilSmithline from what I understand, it's SSH server asking - even if the password authentication is disabled you can try to log in using password. However, even the correct password will be rejected in that case